# FormData() append method (browser compatibility problems)

Tags: javascript

Server-side dev here who's a JS newbie (1 week old). This question is about browser compatibility issues (mobile browsers especially).

I'm trying to use pure JS/Ajax to process image uploads via a web form. Specifically, at one point I'm using the `append` method on `FormData()` with `filename`.

Here's the code:

```
function overwrite_default_submit(e) {
  // block the default behavior
  e.preventDefault();
  // create and populate the form with data
  var form_data = new FormData();
  form_data.append("image", img_to_send, img_name);

  // send the form via AJAX
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', e.target.action);
  xhr.send(form_data);
}
```

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append, browser compatibility for `append` in mobiles is not universal. Two problems cited are:

> XHR in Android 4.0 sends empty content for FormData with blob.

And

> Prior to Gecko 7.0 (Firefox 7.0 / Thunderbird 7.0 / SeaMonkey 2.4),
>   if you specified a Blob as the data to append to the object, the
>   filename reported in the "Content-Disposition" HTTP header was an
>   empty string; this resulted in errors being reported by some servers.
>   Starting in Gecko 7.0 the filename "blob" is sent.

My questions are:

1) What alternative can I use to fix these specific situations?

2) What checks can I put in place to elegantly fall back (e.g. to a non-JS solution - which I've already implemented) in case there's just no way through?

Would love to see illustrative examples of how the experts do it.

---

In case warranted, here's my full code:

```
// converting image data uri to a blob object
function dataURItoBlob(dataURI,mime_type) {
  var byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);//supported
  var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);//supported
  var ia = new Uint8Array(ab);//supported
  for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) { ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i); }//supported
  return new Blob([ab], { type: mime_type });
}
```

The above is called in the following:

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = img_width;
canvas.height = img_height;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.drawImage(source_img, 0, 0, img_width, img_height);
return dataURItoBlob(canvas.toDataURL(mime_type,quality/100),mime_type);
```

And ultimately, the returned blob is appended to a `FormData()` object and sent via Ajax:

```
function overwrite_default_submit(e) {
  // block the default behavior
  e.preventDefault();
  // create and populate the form with data
  var form_data = new FormData();
  form_data.append("image", img_blob, img_name);

  // send the form via AJAX
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  xhr.open('POST', e.target.action);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
  xhr.send(form_data);
}
```